# Flexbox scroll breaks when wrapped in flex-direction: column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to lay out a simple message container that will scroll when needed.  This works as expected when the parent container only contains a header, and the message box, however, when wrapping it in another container and adding a bar on the right the side of the message box, the message box height does not respect the overflow setting and expands past the parent container.  How can I get the message box to scroll while using a column next to it?

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
}
.flex-fill {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.flex-rows {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.message-container {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    overflow-y: auto;
    flex: 1;
}
.message {
    height: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="flex-container flex-fill flex-rows" style="background-color: red; padding: 1rem; height: 500px;">
        <div id="top-bar" style="background-color: purple;">
            <h3>Working Scroll</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="message-container" style="background-color: white; padding: 1rem;">
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container flex-fill flex-rows" style="background-color: green; padding: 1rem; height: 500px;">
        <div id="top-bar" style="background-color: purple;">
            <h3>Broken Scroll</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-container flex-fill" style="background-color: blue; padding: 1rem;">
            <div class="message-container" style="background-color: white; padding: 1rem;">
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            </div>
            <div id="right-bar" style="background-color: orange; width: 50px;">
                <h3>Right</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is a CodePen example.
https://codepen.io/dwpuush/pen/eYzvQQJ

Comment: Just FYI it may help a little to put all your styles in the CSS section rather than splitting some out as inline styles in the HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the `flex-fill` class to allow the element to shrink and also add `min-height:0;` to force the element to [shrink even past its content size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/8620333)

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
}
.flex-fill {
    flex: 1 1 auto; /* instead of 1 0 auto*/
    min-height:0;
}
.flex-rows {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.message-container {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    overflow-y: auto;
    flex: 1;
}
.message {
    height: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="flex-container flex-fill flex-rows" style="background-color: red; padding: 1rem; height: 500px;">
        <div id="top-bar" style="background-color: purple;">
            <h3>Working Scroll</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="message-container" style="background-color: white; padding: 1rem;">
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container flex-fill flex-rows" style="background-color: green; padding: 1rem; height: 500px;">
        <div id="top-bar" style="background-color: purple;">
            <h3>Broken Scroll</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-container flex-fill" style="background-color: blue; padding: 1rem;">
            <div class="message-container" style="background-color: white; padding: 1rem;">
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
                <div class="message">Testing Message</div>
            </div>
            <div id="right-bar" style="background-color: orange; width: 50px;">
                <h3>Right</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm.  I'd tried the min-height change, but had the flex-fill wrong.  Thanks!